# Numeric Value out of Range when Inserting to SQL from R

Tags: sql, r

Edit: Here is the column file for you to try to insert to your database: https://easyupload.io/jls3mk

So I narrowed my problem down to 1 column in my dataframe. It's a numeric column from 0-260000 with NaNs in it.

When I try to insert pred_new_export[46] (only column 46) using this statement:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = con, 
             name = SQL("ML.CreditLineApplicationOutputTemp"), 
             value = pred_new_export[46], overwrite=TRUE)  ## x is any data frame
```

I get the issue:

```
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows) : 
nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 22003: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Numeric value out of range
```

I've looked at this for 2 hours and it's been driving me insane. I can't figure out why it wouldn't insert into a fresh SQL table. The column only contains numbers.

The numbers are within range of the column:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the SQL schema create statement.

```
USE [EDWAnalytics]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [ML].[CreditLineApplicationOutputTemp]    Script Date: 4/20/2022 9:26:22 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [ML].[CreditLineApplicationOutputTemp](
    [MedianIncomeInAgeBracket] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Well is there an out of range value, based on the column type?  Not all SQL numeric columns can store all numeric data.

Comment: The thing is I sorted by lowest and highest and they fall within the 0-260000 range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it has `NaN`s, which many DBMSes do not understand. I suggest you replace all `NaN` with `NA`.

Reprex:

```r
# con <- DBI::dbConnect(..)
DBI::dbExecute(con, "create table quux (num float)")
# [1] 0
df <- data.frame(num=c(1,NA,NaN))
DBI::dbAppendTable(con, "quux", df)
# Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows) : 
#   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision. 
df$num[is.nan(df$num)] <- NA
DBI::dbAppendTable(con, "quux", df)
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from quux")
#   num
# 1   1
# 2  NA
# 3  NA
```

FYI, the version of SQL Server ODBC you are using is rather antiquated: even the [most recent release](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434) of `11` was in 2017. For many reasons, I suggest you upgrade to [ODBC Driver for SQL Server 17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (the 17 has nothing to do with the version of SQL Server to which you are connecting).

FYI, my DBMS/version:

```r
cat(DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select @@version")[[1]], "\n")
# Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU14) (KB5007182) - 15.0.4188.2 (X64) 
#   Nov  3 2021 19:19:51 
#   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
#   Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) <X64>
```

though this is also the case with SQL Server 2016 (and likely other versions).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed response. I swapped my ODBC driver to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. I also did the NaN change, but I'm still getting the same issues. I've compared the field to other fields as well using range. Its numeric range is smaller than other working columns. The values range from 2499 to 250001. The numeric is capable of holding 0-260000. There are no NaNs, only NAs.

Totally at a loss now! I've also uploaded the column file containing the data I'm trying to insert to the database.

Comment: Using *that* data, I can overwrite it multiple times in my local database without error, so it's not the data per se that's doing it. The name of your table suggests that *you* create it at some point, meaning it is unlikely to have unrecognized triggers or constraints; if you did not, perhaps you can ask your DBA to help look for those. There are data types that do not allow floating point up to those values; please edit your question and post the output from `"select * from information_schema.columns where table_name='ML.CreditLineApplicationOutputTemp'"`, it might give us a clue.

Comment: I did create the table myself. The catch though is I drop this table everytime before I call dbwritetable. So it's basically a brand new table everytime. I'm not sure why an error would come up if I'm essentially performing a select * into everytime.

Comment: Do you `CREATE TABLE` each time, or rely on `DBI::dbWriteTable` to infer the correct field types? Again, knowing more about its schema might give us a good clue.

Comment: I use dbWriteTable to infer correct field types, so it is possible the issue occurs there. I also updated my post with the CREATE schema for the table.

Comment: Thanks. Have you looked at the output from the query I suggested? I includes a lot of information that the `CREATE TABLE` query does not. I don't know that it will be helpful, but it's a start.

Comment: Holy, I think I got it to work. I was querying the information_schema as you requested and realized somewhere along the way my table got created under two different schemas and was trying to insert into a very old one where the formatting did not match up. I deleted that table and tried fresh and it seemed to work!

Comment: FYI, the use of `information_schema.columns` has a lot of information that means little to most, but it can provide a lot of context (including radix of fields, etc). That pseudo-table is also not encouraged by the more-adroit DBAs, meaning there are perhaps more-modern ways of gaining insight (e.g., `sys.objects` pseudo table); regardless, it works well, and is supported on many DBMSes with very close similarity, so I stick with it until somebody can demonstrate where it is bad (hasn't happened yet). Glad it worked.

Comment: I had the same error, then found i had divisions by zero, once i filtered out these divisions by 0 mssql took the tables with no problem using dbi